# In Laravel How to Filters Products according to attributes and attribute options

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and working on E-commerce Website.

I am trying to display product attributes and attribute options on the front end but I can't.

**My Function**

```php
$data['product_attributes'] = Pro_attributes::with('attribute_options')->get();
```

**My Blade file**

```xml
@foreach ($product_attributes as $item)
  <div class="sidebar__item sidebar__item__color--option">
    <h4>{{ $item->name }}</h4>
    
    @foreach ($item->attribute_options as $option)
      @if ($option->name)
        <div class="form-check">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            value="{{ $option->id }}"
            id="{{ $option->id }}"
            name="{{ $option->name }}">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ $option->id }}">{{ $option->name }}</label>
        </div>
      @endif
    @endforeach
  </div>
@endforeach
```

**Relations**

```php
class Pro_attributes extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function attribute_options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(pro_attributes_options::class, 'attribute_id');
    }
}
```

and

```php
class Pro_attributes_options extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function attribute()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Pro_attributes::class, 'attribute_id');
    }
}
```

but in display

[image: My shop page sidebar]

because i now why this data is repeating because i have stored data in such a way

**My product Attribute table**

[image: Product attributes table]

**and my product atttribute option table**

[image: Product attribute's options table]

now I think you can understand my problem of repeated attribute and their options
i've tried my best used groupBy or unique method but i am failed to do this because by using them my all attributes and their related options were not displaying
i mean if i filter unique attribute name color then only one option according to that color was displaying not other option

please replay iam waiting for your response

Comment: anybody reply please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said, the problem is your attributes are duplicated in the database. It doesn't look like a good design.

You could use collection methods to further group the data in the blade file.

That `@if ($option->name)` shouldn't be necessary.

```xml
@foreach ($product_attributes->unique('name') as $item)
  <div class="sidebar__item sidebar__item__color--option">
    <h4>{{ $item->name }}</h4>
    
    @php
      $options = $product_attributes
        ->where('name', $item->name)
        ->flatMap->attribute_options
        ->unique('name')
        ->sortBy('name');
    @endphp

    @foreach ($options as $option)
      <div class="form-check">
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="radio"
          value="{{ $option->id }}"
          id="{{ $option->id }}"
          name="{{ $option->name }}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ $option->id }}">{{ $option->name }}</label>
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
@endforeach
```

This won't solve your database design problems though. It will just worsen it in the long run.