# Filter Products Dynamically according to attributes in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have stored Products and their attributes, and attribute options as well in the database.

In this way, I sent product attribute_data into Database

**Function**

```
$data['product_attributes'] = Pro_attributes::with('attribute_options')->get();
```

**Blade File (Displaying Data)**

```
 @foreach ($product_attributes->unique('name') as $item)
<div class="sidebar__item sidebar__item__color--option">
<h4>{{ $item->name }}</h4>

@php
$options = $product_attributes
->where('name', $item->name)
->flatMap->attribute_options->unique('name')
->sortBy('name');
@endphp

@foreach ($options as $option)
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="{{ $option->id }}"
    id="{{ $option->id }}"
    name="{{ strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $item->name)) }}">
<label class="form-check-label"
    for="{{ $option->id }}">{{ $option->name }}</label>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

**Result**

[Frontend Displaying Attributes and options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUrnc.png)

Now After Submitting form **dd($request->all());**

```
array:4 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\Frontend\ShopController.php:59
  "color" => "47"
  "size" => "50"
]
```

**as my relations are**

from product.php

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Pro_attributes::class, 'product_id');
}
```

from pro_attibutes.php

```
public function attribute_options()
{
    return $this->hasMany(pro_attributes_options::class, 'attribute_id');
}
```

and from pro_attibutes_options.php

```
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Pro_attributes::class, 'attribute_id');
}
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
}
```

Now Please help to Filter products dynamically having these attributes

as I have tried much to make this functionality but i can't.

i do not want to filter this way

```
if ($request->filled('color')) {
$color = (array) $request->input('color');
$products->whereHas('attributes.attribute_options', function ($query) use ($color) {
$query->whereIn('id', $color);
});
}
```

because in this way we've to create code one by one for each attribute
but I want to make it dynamic because in the future I have to create more filters.

Please help me I am waiting for your response.

Comment: Please delete your previous pleading comment. It does not help your case! As pointed out in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76641458/1191247) to your previous question, you need to resolve the issues with your data model first. Having multiple attributes named `color` and multiple colors named `white` is a recipe for disaster. A [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+product+attribute+values) returns lots of relevant articles and tutorials. If `prod1` and `prod2` are both `white` they should both be related to the same `attribite_value` record.